# Create Custom Field Annotation to check Null value in java

Tags: java, java-8, annotations

I need to create Custom annotation in java to check null value *i.e

`@NonNull`

```
public void test(String [] input , String str){
}
```

How to add the annoation to **`input`** and **`str`** fields

Answer (score 0):

When creating your Annotation class, you have to add the `@Target` annotation to mark where this Annotation is valid. For parameters this would be `ElementType.PARAMETER`.

This minimal example will compile. (The Interface is a private nested class here, but you will want to define it in its own .java file)

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
private static @interface NonNull {
}

public void test(@NonNull String[] input, @NonNull String str) {
}
```

Note that this does not provide any null-checking, but tells the caller that this parameters may not be null in the function.

I'm pretty sure you can implement some kind of null-checking in the annotation class, but I'm not sure, so that has to be answered by someone else or you can probably look at some existing implementations of `@NonNull` interfaces.